# Kendo Tabstrip: Call tab content's javascript function whenever a tab is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo tabstrip, with multiple tab contents, each of them include  Javascript function `$(document).ready()...`

However, it only executes at the very first time the tab is selected (the content loaded),  when I select another tab and come back to this tab, as the content is already loaded, `$(document).ready()` is not called.

Is there any possible method to make `$(document).ready()` execute every time when a tab is selected? (Re-render the tab content every time is not an option due to performance consideration...)

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function for each of your individual tabs and wire up a client-side event to pick up when the TabStrip selection changed using [some of the available events](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/TabStripEventBuilder) :

```
@Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("YourTabStrip")
            .Events(events => events.Select("tabChanged"))

<script>
    function tabChanged(e){
        // Get your selected tab using (e.item);
        var index = $("#YourTabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip").select().index();

        // Based on the tab, trigger a function
        switch(index){
            default:
            case 0:
                LoadContentA();
            case 1:
                LoadContentB();
        }
    }
</script>
```

And you could refactor each of your `$(document).ready()` calls within your individual tabs to simply call one of the functions specified within the `switch` statement :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        LoadContentA();
    });

    function LoadContentA(){
        // Do work here
    }
</script>
```

I'm sure if you read through the [available Javascript API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip) and [ASP.NET MVC API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/TabStripEventBuilder), it might help provide some additional insight on a better way to tackle this.